# How to transfer files from Windows 10 partition to new Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, thunderbird

My brilliant techy son has convinced me to move to linux/ubuntu for everyday use, and installed Ubuntu on a separate partition on one of my pc's.  I need to save the Windows 10 partition for 2-3 programs I use occasionally that are only for Windows, but I want to transfer everything else, files and apps, to the Ubuntu partition on the same machine, so I can use ubuntu as my primary os.  Most of the files are already linux friendly, i.e. I use thunderbird for email, libreoffice & so forth.

I'm afraid I need step-by-step instructions, as I have never used ubuntu before.  Is there an article in the documentation that gives this how-to?  I looked and could not find it.

Your help will be greatly appreciated by this ancient who first learned to use a computer on a time-shared IBM 360!!  Regards, Laurel

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, although it would probably be easier to configure your ubuntu system to load the windows drive on boot. Ubuntu is able to read the Windows filesystem formats natively. The benefit of this method is that any changes made in ubuntu will be reflected in windows the next time you use it.

First, you need to grab the unique identifier for your partition.

```
# List all drives
fdisk -l
# Get the unique ID for your drive
blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda2
```

Replace `/dev/sda2` with the drive you want to mount at boot. Take note of this value, you will need it for later. Next you will create the new folder where windows will be mounted each time you turn on Ubuntu. If you want windows to be easily accessible from your home folder, then you could run this command to make a folder called windows:

```
mkdir ~/windows
```

Next, create a backup of the file we are about to edit.

```
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

The fstab file determines what drives are loaded at boot. Edit `/etc/fstab` and append the following at the bottom:

```
UUID=12102C02102CEB83     ~/windows     ntfs-3g
```

Replace the numbers after UUID= with the output of the earlier `blkid` command. Save the file and restart your computer. You should have the windows filesystem auto mounted in your home directory.

Comment: **You do NOT want to mount your Windows C: for any length of time, as you will corrupt it.** To most easily SHARE files between Windows and Ubuntu is to create a new NTFS partition to hold those files. Windows apps cannot be used in Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows fast boot feature? Or is there another way you can corrupt the ntfs partition by mounting it on boot in linux? I do this with my arch-windows dual boot without issue. I did disable the fast boot feature though in my case.

Comment: Fast boot needs to be disabled, as you mention. However, other than to quickly copy off some files from the Windows C: disk, any kind of file/directory structure changes can cause Windows to no longer boot, or require a Windows repair disc to fix. Windows is VERY fussy about this.

Comment: 5 years later and i still haven't had any issues with my drive being corrupted so i am not sure what you say is correct.